# Last activity field in Django's user sessions

Tags: django

How and when exactly does `last_activity` in Django sessions get updated? I've been testing a Django app, and my last activity in user sessions is logged as several days ago, even though I logged in yesterday as well. What could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a direct result of [when sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved)

> By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session
>   has been modified – that is if any of its dictionary values have been
>   assigned or deleted:

If you want to mark a user as being active, you can place the following code in key areas of your app to mark the session as being modified so that it will be saved again in the storage

```
request.session.modified = True
```

Alternatively you can use [SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) to make sure that the session gets saved on each and every request this of course comes with an extra hit to the db.

Comment: Thinking out aloud here: if a user's using mobile internet to connect to my website, we can be pretty sure their IP will change very fluidly. And IP's a field in sessions. So a new row would then be created each time?

Comment: Hello Hassan, django sessions are not tied to IPs but to the browser so this will not have any impact. If the browser is killed due to low memory that might lead to a new entry in the session table. but we are supposed to clear out stale sessions periodically

Comment: Howdy! You're right. I was conflating django-user-sessions (a library I use to be able to access sessions as ORM objects) with Django's inbuilt sessions. The former actually stores last_acitvity in its sessions table, whereas the latter doesn't.

Comment: So I suppose, if I was to give a "log out from all other places" functionality to my users, I'd have to delete all other sessions (save the current one) from the sessions table?

Comment: yes, you would need to find related session objects and delete them